# Using handlers to play a sound after baking

Tags: python, scripting, fluid-simulation

Browsing other questions and the documentation, I've been able to create this simple script + run it in my project. However, nothing happens - I've tried baking a fluid sim's data/mesh multiple times, and the sound never plays. I have tested the sound separately and it plays fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Are the handlers I'm using not called for this type of bake?

```
import bpy
import winsound

def beep_when_done(dummy):
    winsound.PlaySound("Notification.IM", winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)

bpy.app.handlers.object_bake_cancel.append(beep_when_done)
bpy.app.handlers.object_bake_complete.append(beep_when_done)
```

Comment: are you 100% sure, that your file path is ok? blender uses a different filepath than windows does. Maybe try opening a txt file and print it out - with the txt file at the same folder as your Notification.im. If this works, you can use the same filepath for your sound file. I had the same problem....and it was "just" the path ;)

Comment: Yes, the sound plays fine when run from a script in blender that only plays it with that exact line.